# error message of No module named 'tensorflow' in GCP AI Platform Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, installation, python-import, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I launched a notebook with GCP AI Platform. Then, I tried to install tensorflow by:

`import tensorflow as tf`

There is an error message of

> No module named 'tensorflow'

I tried to install it by:

`!pip install -U --user tensorflow==1.14.0`

But the same error message appeared. As it is a GCP platform, I wonder why I need to install tensorflow. During Coursera training, I can import tensorflow directly without installation. I wonder if I missed anything.

Grateful if you can help.

Thank you

Comment: Aren't the AI platform notebooks on GCP available with pre installed Tensorflow versions? Did you chose the right notebook type?

Comment: Thank you and you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably selected an instance type that doesn't have `tensorflow` pre-installed.

After you install a Python dependency you will have to restart the Python Kernel for updates to take effect by clicking on `Kernel->Restart Kernel...`.

Comment: Did you manage to import tensorflow eventually? If my answer helped you, please accept it as correct.